# Express not doing anything but sending HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using an `app.post` method in Express like so:

```
app.post('/race', function(req,res) {
  let raceResponse = {
    user_name: req.body.userName
  }
  console.log('Express has received race.');

  //Socket.IO
  let race = io.of('/race').on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user has entered the race!');
    socket.on('racePageReady', function() {
      console.log('race page ready recieved');
      socket.emit('racePageInfo', raceResponse);
    });

    socket.on('createRoom', function(roomName) {
      socket.join(roomName);
      let clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName].sockets;
      console.log("A room with the name " + roomName + "was created.");
      console.log(clients);
      socket.emit('roomCreated', clients);
    });

    socket.on('joinRoom', function(roomName) {
      socket.join(roomName);
      let clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName].sockets;
      console.log('A user joined the room with the name: ' + roomName + ". The user's name is " + raceResponse.user_name);
      console.log(clients);
      socket.emit('roomCreated', clients);
    });
  });

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/race/index.html'));
}
```

The page is being sent fine, but the `console.log` and all the other Socket.IO stuff just doesn't happen. I'm finding this peculiar, because I have a *different* `app.post` method that works just fine, all `console.logging` and Socket.IO business happens. Here's the code:

```
app.post('/city', function(req,res) {
  let cityResponse = {
    user_name: req.body.userName
  }

  console.log('Express has received city.');

  //Socket.IO
  let city = io.of('/city').on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.id = Math.random();
    socket.name = cityResponse.user_name;
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket; //defined earlier

    User.onConnect(socket); //defined earlier

    socket.on('cityPageReady', function() {
      socket.emit('cityPageInfo', cityResponse);
      console.log('city page ready recieved');
    });

    console.log('A user has connected to the city!');
    console.log("Socket: " + socket);
    console.log("Socket ID: " + socket.id);
    console.log("SOCKET_LIST: ");
    console.log(SOCKET_LIST);

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg, user) {
      console.log('User ' + user + ' sent the message : ' + msg);
      socket.emit('chat message', msg, user);
    });
  });

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/city/index.html'));
});
```

As far as I can tell, both methods look pretty much the same, except for the Socket.IO stuff in the middle. I'm fairly certain that the `io.of` method is correct, as it's working for the City page, but not the race.

The only other difference is the way that the two pages are accessed. The City page is accessed through a HTML form with an `action` attribute, whereas the Race page is accessed through a HTML link (on the City page) with a `href` attribute.

Both methods are shown below:

**CITY**

```
<form id="cityForm" action="http://localhost:4000/city" method="POST">
  User name: <input type="text" name="userName">
  button type="submit" id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**RACE**

```
<div><a href="http://localhost:4000/race"></div>
```

Can anyone see why this peculiar behaviour is occuring? If any other information is needed please let me know so that I can include it.

Comment: Should your `race` code point to `city`? And btw, this will send a `get`.

Comment: Your comments don't match the code snippets: **RACE** shows URL to city. Assuming that you actually meant `/race` in that URL, then there is no name property passed in the request.

Comment: That was a typo. The div actually points to `http://localhost:4000/race`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clicking an on HTML link, the browser does a GET HTML request. When you submit a Form (with method="POST"), the browser does a POST request.

When using `app.post()`, you tell express to listen for POST requests. If you want express to listen for GET requests, you should use `app.get()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there any way to change a HTML link so that it does a POST request instead?

Comment: Why not just change the NodeJS method to app.get()?

Comment: You can't change a `<a>` link to send a POST request, but you can create a form: `<form action="/race" method="post"><button type="submit">The link</button></form>` and use CSS to style the button to look like a link

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ideally, I'd like the request to not be shown in the browser. [This page](http://theusualstuff.com/handle-form-data-express-get-post-method/) is what I used to learn about them originally.

Comment: @William - just FYI - you've misunderstood what that page says. You definitely don't want your form submitted with a GET. But, the anchor tag you have will only show `http://localhost:4000/race` in the address bar - changing your server method to `app.get()` doesn't affect that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn So, does this mean that I have to use Errorname's method of using a form instead? Also, what's so bad about using a GET in this context?

Comment: You are not sending data - so a form is inappropriate. You are only requesting a resource - the proper verb to use is GET. I would change the server method to `app.get()`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The data is being sent with Socket.IO. That's probably not the right way to do things, but it works. Does this mean that Express _itself_ isn't sending any data?